# UITextView outline text

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics, uitextview

I am creating an application and am looking to use a `UITextView` and subclass `UITextView` to outline the text. Using a `UILabel` it can be done using the example below but `UITextView` does not offer `drawTextinRect`. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to outline text in a `UITextView`?

```
- (void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)rect
{    
    CGSize shadowOffset = self.shadowOffset;

    UIColor *textColor = self.textColor;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    self.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, [[self font] pointSize]/8.0);

    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextStroke);
    self.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [super drawTextInRect:rect];

    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
    self.textColor = textColor;
    self.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);

    [super drawTextInRect:rect];

    self.shadowOffset = shadowOffset;
}
```

Comment: I use the above code in UILabels too, and now I need to use it for the label on a UIButton too. So any help here may help me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` because `UITextView` is a subclass of `UIView` and implement your custom drawing there.

Comment: Right, I suppose I need some direction on how to go about doing so. The current code does not produce the same results when applied to drawRect.

Comment: You don't quite understand what you are doing I think. You are responsible to draw the text and on top of it for each line of text you have to draw a line. Or you can just search for a open source textView that all ready does this.

Comment: Are there any open-source for that?